# SOAP XML select Nodes

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I'm trying to get the SOAP XML Values in C# Objects but currently I can't select any node and so get no value.

This is the XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<AddTwoStr xmlns="http://cpu1147/AB_TestWebApp/">
<InputParameters>
<Parameter>
<DataType>string</DataType>
<Name>String1</Name>
<Value>test</Value>
</Parameter>
<Parameter>
<DataType>string</DataType>
<Name>String2</Name>
<Value>test</Value
></Parameter>
</InputParameters>
</AddTwoStr>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

the XML is stored in the following c# Code :

```
// Get raw request body
            Stream receiveStream = HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream;
            // Move to begining of input stream and read
            receiveStream.Position = 0;
            //Webrequest als StreamReader
            //StreamReader mystream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            StreamReader mystream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);

            string test = mystream.ReadToEnd();

            XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
            document.LoadXml(test);
```

Does anyone have a solution for me to select the Values of String1 and String2 ??

Thanks and Kind regards,
Chris

Comment: You say you get no value....What error / problem are you encountering?

Comment: String 1 and String2 are itself values in above XML. can you specify what tag values are you looking for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, SOAP requests that come over the wire are deserialized into known types that are usually provided by the consumed services reference information which is generated when adding a service reference. I appreciate that you could potentially be receiving this payload from elsewhere, but i still find it often easier to use strongly typed classes to help extract the values you need. You could of course load the XML into an XPath doc or something and traverse the nodes and elements within.

In the below example, I've taken your xml and have created the classes required to de-serialize.

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class Envelope
    {

        private EnvelopeBody bodyField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public EnvelopeBody Body
        {
            get
            {
                return this.bodyField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.bodyField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public partial class EnvelopeBody
    {

        private AddTwoStr addTwoStrField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "http://cpu1147/AB_TestWebApp/")]
        public AddTwoStr AddTwoStr
        {
            get
            {
                return this.addTwoStrField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.addTwoStrField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://cpu1147/AB_TestWebApp/")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://cpu1147/AB_TestWebApp/", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class AddTwoStr
    {

        private AddTwoStrParameter[] inputParametersField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Parameter", IsNullable = false)]
        public AddTwoStrParameter[] InputParameters
        {
            get
            {
                return this.inputParametersField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.inputParametersField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://cpu1147/AB_TestWebApp/")]
    public partial class AddTwoStrParameter
    {

        private string dataTypeField;

        private string nameField;

        private string valueField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public string DataType
        {
            get
            {
                return this.dataTypeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.dataTypeField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return this.nameField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.nameField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string Value
        {
            get
            {
                return this.valueField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.valueField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Next we use the XMLSerializer to de-serialize the xml into an instance of the class.
In the below example, I've loaded your xml from a local file.

```
Envelope data;
var xml = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\test.xml");

 using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml)))
 {
      XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));
      data = (Envelope)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
 }

 //Access the parameters here via an index.
 var val = data.Body.AddTwoStr.InputParameters[0].Value;
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot that helps. Now I can enter the XML. The next Question is the Response. I have to set it as XML and try the following

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace AB_TestWebApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Zusammenfassungsbeschreibung für WebService1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://cpu1147/AB_TestWebApp/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(true)]
    // Wenn der Aufruf dieses Webdiensts aus einem Skript zulässig sein soll, heben Sie mithilfe von ASP.NET AJAX die Kommentarmarkierung für die folgende Zeile auf. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {


        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
        public string AddTwoStr()
        {
            //--//
            // Get raw request body
            Stream receiveStream = HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream;
            // Move to begining of input stream and read
            receiveStream.Position = 0;
            //Webrequest als StreamReader
            //StreamReader mystream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            //StreamReader mystream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);

            //string test = mystream.ReadToEnd();

            //XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
            //document.LoadXml(test);
            //XElement xdocument = XElement.Parse(test);

            Envelope data;
            //var xml = document.Value;

            //using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(receiveStream.ToString())))
            using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));
                data = (Envelope)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
            }

            //Access the parameters here via an index.
            string String1 = data.Body.AddTwoStr.InputParameters[0].Value;
            string String2 = data.Body.AddTwoStr.InputParameters[1].Value;

            //--//

            XElement sofon_response = new XElement("Parameter",
            new XElement("DataType", "String"),
            new XElement("Name", "WebResponse"),
            new XElement("Value", string.Concat(String1, String2))
            );

            return sofon_response.ToString();
        }


        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }


        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", IsNullable = false)]
        public partial class Envelope
        {

            private EnvelopeBody bodyField;

            /// <remarks/>
            public EnvelopeBody Body
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.bodyField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.bodyField = value;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public partial class EnvelopeBody
        {

            private AddTwoStrPar addTwoStrField;

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "http://cpu1147/AB_TestWebApp/")]
            public AddTwoStrPar AddTwoStr
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.addTwoStrField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.addTwoStrField = value;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://cpu1147/AB_TestWebApp/")]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://cpu1147/AB_TestWebApp/", IsNullable = false)]
        public partial class AddTwoStrPar
        {

            private AddTwoStrParameter[] inputParametersField;

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Parameter", IsNullable = false)]
            public AddTwoStrParameter[] InputParameters
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.inputParametersField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.inputParametersField = value;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://cpu1147/AB_TestWebApp/")]
        public partial class AddTwoStrParameter
        {

            private string dataTypeField;

            private string nameField;

            private string valueField;

            /// <remarks/>
            public string DataType
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.dataTypeField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.dataTypeField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            public string Name
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.nameField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.nameField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            public string Value
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.valueField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.valueField = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Problem now is that the XML is now not well formatted, see this example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><AddTwoStrResponse xmlns="http://cpu1147/AB_TestWebApp/"><AddTwoStrResult>&lt;Parameter&gt;
  &lt;DataType&gt;String&lt;/DataType&gt;
  &lt;Name&gt;WebResponse&lt;/Name&gt;
  &lt;Value&gt;HalloChristian&lt;/Value&gt;
&lt;/Parameter&gt;</AddTwoStrResult></AddTwoStrResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

What I Need to give back is that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <WebMethodResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <WebMethodResult>
                <Parameter>
                    <DataType>String</DataType>
                    <Name>WebResponse</Name>
                    <Value>Hallo World</Value>
                </Parameter>
            </WebMethodResult>
        </WebMethodResponse>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode/>
            <faultstring/>
            <faultactor/>
            <detail/>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I tried serval times to deserialize but I get Always the error message "wrong character in XML"